# Handling FireDAC Errorcode

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

I have Delphi 10.3 and I work with Firebird 3.0. I would like to know how I can capture the error message that Firebird gives with the FireDAC components. Before, with the FIBPlus components, I could do it in the following way:

```
if (E is EFIBError) then
  case EFIBError(E).IBErrorCode of
    335544347 : scMessageDlg('Field NAME is Null',mtError,[mbOk],0);
  end;
  Action := daAbort;
```

Comment: Have you read any of the documentation or searched for FireDAC exceptions? At least start with: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Handling_Errors_(FireDAC)

Comment: No clue why [FIBPlus defines all error codes in decimal (like `335544347`)](https://github.com/madorin/fibplus/blob/master/IB_ErrorCodes.pas) when hexadecimal (`$1400001b`) would look so much easier to comprehend and differentiate. Anyway: better use the constant `isc_not_valid` instead of numbers.

Comment: In the help topic I linked one line might help here: **TFDDBError has an ErrorCode property, which is the native DBMS error code.**

Comment: @AmigoJack The Firebird error codes are all [documented](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-appx02-sqlcodes) in decimal (and the same goes for `iberror.h` from the `include` directory of a Firebird install), which makes it easier to match up errors with the documentation.